# How do I tell which R packages to cite in my paper?

Tags: r, citations

The question of [R "stats" citation for a scientific paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688758/r-stats-citation-for-a-scientific-paper) makes me wonder how I would enumerate all the R packages that I ought to cite when using R in an academic paper. How would I get a list of packages that I loaded and need citation?

Comment: See this answer about `grateful` package https://stackoverflow.com/a/46781771/7886302

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer to [How to find out which package version is loaded in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103189/how-to-find-out-which-package-version-is-loaded-in-r) , I see that we can use the `sessionInfo()` function to see what packages have been loaded (though not necessarily used).

The following gets the base packages as a vector and concatenates it with the names of the loaded packages. Then we apply the `citation` function to each.

```
packages_in_use <- c( sessionInfo()$basePkgs, names( sessionInfo()$loadedOnly ) )
the_citations_list <- lapply( X=packages_in_use, FUN=citation)
the_citations_list
```

Comment: A blanket **R** citation with the version number should be sufficient for the base packages. But if you used specific, non-base, packages, you could cite them as above.