# How to cite the R Language Definition

Tags: r

We can cite R with `citation()`. See also e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688758/r-stats-citation-for-a-scientific-paper). However, I'm unsure whether this is also the right way to cite the [*R Language Definition*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Computing-on-the-language) specifically.

What is the best way to cite the *R Language Definition* specifically? `citation()` or something else?

Comment: The ``citation()`` function is doing a pretty good job. I think the output (here with data.table) is nice and professional : ``Matt Dowle and Arun Srinivasan (2019). data.table: Extension of `data.frame`. R package version 1.12.2.
  https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=data.table``. I think this is a good way to cite the R Language Definition too.

Comment: @Gainz: Of course. It is a great way. I'm just unsure whether I can refer to the *R Language Definition* specifically using `citation()` or some other mechanisms. Since `citation()` will print the link "https://www.r-project.org/" and not the link directly to the language definition..

Comment: I mean I just do ``citation("base")`` to cite R. Is that what you want? The output is ``R Core Team (2018). R: A language and environment for statistical computing. R Foundation for Statistical
  Computing, Vienna, Austria. URL https://www.R-project.org/.``. I think this is a good way to do it.

Comment: No, not really what I am searching for.. AFAIK, `citation()` and `citation("base")` are equivalent. Both point to "r-project.org" (and not directly to the R Language Definition). But maybe it's ok to just use `citation()` when citing the R Language Definition.

Comment: yes but you are citing R which is made by R-Project, that is why the function return this. The output also give us : ``We have invested a lot of time and effort in creating R, please cite it when using it for data analysis. See also
‘citation("pkgname")’ for citing R packages.`` So I personally think this is the best way to cite R. Maybe someone could give you a better or different answer tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Like you would cite any other web resource](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3587/42), since that is how it’s published. E.g. in BibTeX notation:

> ```
> @misc{RLang,
>   title = {{R Language Definition}},
>   author = {{R Core Team}},
>   year = 2019,
>   howpublished = {\url{https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html}},
>   note = {Accessed: 2019-06-17}
> }
> ```

Comment: That is a good answer. You could also use the one provide from the ``citation()`` function which return (for BibTeX/LaTex) : ``@Manual{,
    title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
    author = {{R Core Team}},
    organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
    address = {Vienna, Austria},
    year = {2019},
    url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
  }``. I guess it depend if you prefer to link to the R language definition or not.